# In R how do I get the position at which there is a change in the element of a vector

Tags: r

For example, I have a sequence:

```
seq = sample(c(0,1), 11, replace = T)
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Desired output:

```
1,2,5,11
```

Comment: Unclear what the question is. How does the output match up with that sequence?

Comment: Also please use `set.seed(...)` to guarantee reproducibility when drawing random samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
vec <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
c(1, which(diff(vec)!=0)+1)
#[1]  1  2  5 11
```

Checking whether `diff()` is different from zero is used to detect a change in the sequence. The index where the change occurs is retrieved with `which()`. The concatenation of the result with a leading 1 and the shifting of the index numbers by +1 is done because `diff()` reduces the length of the vector by one and the desired output contains 1 as the first index.

Comment: Thank for your response